# Why does vcvarsall.bat seem to not take effect in FarManager

Tags: far-manager

If I run `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"` from a normal cmd.com I have access to cl.exe, and nmake among other things. However, if I run if from [Far Manager](http://farmanager.com/) I do not.

[image: Cmd.exe]

[image: Farmanager]

Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Go to the directory with CL.exe file in it and call it there from within the Far Manager; otherwise, call the full path to the CL.exe from the Far Manager interface. Obviously there's an environmental variable it cannot access to see CL.exe from it as CMD.exe can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a plugin call [FarCall](http://plugring.farmanager.com/plugin.php?pid=823&l=en) that allows you to do this. You install it and then you can call the batch file preceded with `call:`

> call: "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"